# Magento - moving extension from left/right column to main

Tags: magento

I try to move an ext: `Customers who bought this product also purchased` from default left/right column to main column under the product, but I don't know how to do this.

I try to change the line `<product_detail_leftposition translate="label">` to `<product_page translate="label">` in `system.xml` file but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you might want to move that question over to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The site is still in beta, automatic migration is not possible. But you can just login there, ask the question and delete this one here (or add a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding it to the Products view page section inside your layout XML. Add the block inside the content reference block, somewhere at the bottom.

Make sure it's inside the  handle as this defines the structure used on the product view page.

app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[themename]/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
   ...
    <reference name="content">
       ...
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!-- Other blocks etc here.. add at the bottom -->
            <block type="module/block" name="yourblock" as="yourblock"  />
        </block>
    </reference>
 </catalog_product_view>
```

This should automatically output the block for you if you add it in here, although that depends on the theme you are using.

if it doesn't automatically show, you may need to add a line to your view to display the block:

app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[themename]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php // use the block name used in the XML config.. ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('yourblock') ?>
```

Comment: there is one file bought.xml with this block:
`<block type="bought/bought" name="right.bought" before="-">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="catalog/bought/product_detail_rightposition">
     <template>bought/sidebar.phtml</template> 
    </action>
</block>`

Comment: i modify it to:
`<block type="bought/bought" name="right.bought" before="-" as="bought" template="catalog/bought/sidebar.phtml">
                  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
             </block>` and nothing has happen